# escape < in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to make a small script in python.
What I want to do the script is to print a html statement, so I tried:

```
print "\<option value\"1\"\> zzz \ </ option \>
```

the " are fine, but the `" <"`  and   `"> "` are not.

in short, my question is how I can escape the `>` and `<` ?

Comment: Please do not use the `homework` tag, it is being removed.

Comment: What makes you think you need to escape those symbols?

Comment: Do you mean like replacing `<` with `&lt;`? Also, what's the **expected** output vs **actual** output?

Comment: `print '<option value="1">zzz</option>'` would make it a lot easier to read...

Comment: This question may have been edited to the extent it's meaning has changed - I think some input from the OP is needed to clarify *exactly* what was being asked.

Comment: my expected ouput is: <option value="1">zz</option>
and my actual ouput is: &lt option value="1" &gt zzz &lt /option &gt

Comment: @CrazyHorse Is this going through some kind of framework? If you are getting that output, then you are not just printing normally from Python - which will not turn symbols into HTML entities.

Comment: I can replace the " with ' but the output is the same

Comment: crazyhorse, you should reply to @Lattyware question.

Answer (score 2):

Python strings can contain `"<>"` happily, there is no need to escape them.

```
>>> "<"
'<'
```

The only character that needs escaping is the style of quote you used to surround the string - this is so Python can tell you do not mean to end the string there. In general, that can be avoided by using the other type of quote so escaping isn't needed (with the obvious exception of strings that contain both type of quote), e.g:

```
>>> print('<option value="1">zzz</option>')
<option value="1">zzz</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

If you simply want to output `>` or `<`, there is no need to escape them since these aren't interpreted inside a Python string.

If, on the other hand, you want to parse and output symbols as html entities, I would advise looking at something a little more complete, like:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Doing it by hand will only bring you headaches, and you're sure to miss several cases.